# To interview at another company (B) after accepting an offer from company (A)

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer, new-job

I am in a little bit of fix. Recently I had been interview by a company "A", and received a job offer from them, which I formally accepted by signing. As with desperate candidates, I had applied to other positions too, before being interviewed at company A. My dilemma came after I got a call for an interview from company 'B', which is kind of better in terms of brand. I also like the job description.

Personally I feel that it is ethically not correct, or unprofessional to get an interview at the other company. So, I have already informed company 'B' that I have an offer from company 'A'. However they are still interested in interviewing me. I am also not being greedy, as I am more interested in job description with salary being almost equal.

So what do you suggest in this regard?

Answer (score 8):

**Short Answer:** You have signed a contract to start work with Company A, you should not break this contract unless you have a very, very good reason to.

You don't just "have an offer" from Company A, you have a contract to start with them.  Legally and ethically you have committed to commence work with them, and they would have already put resources towards that happening.

Company B doesn't really care, as it's not them who will get in any sort of trouble if you decide to break your contract with Company A.  They are just fishing, and besides, have you told them you have actually *signed* the contract, not just had the offer?

Ethically, legally, and professionally, I would strongly recommend taking your job with Company A.  If you decide you wish to leave at a later date, do it then.  But it may damage your professional reputation to cancel at this point.  It *can* be done, but think very carefully about it first.

Comment: Legally: I don't think that holds in all locations (a lot of US states are right to work states, either party can cancel the contract at any time and walk away). Even if it is not a right to work state anybody can cancel a contract just read the terms for cancellation. If there are no explicit terms then you are free to walk away.

Comment: Ethically: I also don't agree. You seem to want to hold the employee to a higher standard than a company. If the company could a hire a cheaper person they would do so at a drop of the hat and cancel your contract. That's what business do.

Answer (score 6):

> My dilemma came after I got a call for an interview from company 'B'
>
> Personally I feel that it is ethically not correct, or unprofessional
>   to get an interview at the other company.
>
> So what do you suggest in this regard?

For me, there's no dilemma here.

Either you value your word, your reputation, and your personal ethics, or you don't.

I suggest that you think about which is more important to you - the potential of the job at company B or your reputation, and then act accordingly.

Once I accept a new job, I'm all in. I don't look back and inform other parties that I'm no longer interested. My personal reputation is worth a lot to me. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: But you will accept a new job at somepoint (or do you work for the same company for life)? So the question becomes what is the minimum period you would stay?

Comment: And if you value your word, your reputation and your personal ethics, be sure that the salary increase with the new company is more than that value :-D. Sorry, I just could not resist it.

Comment: This answer seems to assume that even *going to the interview* is dishonest. It is certainly posible to go to the interview with company B *while still honouring your contract with company A*. Companies are not love interests. Going to talk to another company is not like you're seeing another woman on the side.

Answer (score 5):

All you have is an offer for an interview.

Go to the interview. There is nothing ethically or legally wrong with going to an interview. If they don't offer you a position then no problem you have a job.

Its only at the point where they offer you a job that you have a dilemma. With an alternative job offer you will have more facts at your disposal to make a decision with. Company B may make an offer that just makes it incompatible for you or they make an offer that makes it impossible to turn down.

Now if you do break the agreement with A their may be repercussions down the road. But **ONLY** if you ever re-apply to A in the future and only during the application processes. This is an unlikely scenario unless A and B are the only two companies in this sector.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The catch is that company 'A' has verbally confirmed that they would get an assignment in my area of interest, while company 'B' has the same assignment in plate. Again the place which I am in is a very closed community. People know each other. 

So, now I am feeling that the right strategy would be to try the job at company 'A'. Unless it doesn't turn out to be as per expectations, I should not back out of this offer. This is primarily because they hired me after taking all my requirements into account.

Answer (score 3):

You've already told company B that you've accepted company A's offer, and they still want to talk to you. It doesn't hurt your reputation or violate any system of ethics that I am aware of to talk to them, as long as you continue to state your intention to work for A.

If B offers you 30% more than of what A is offering you, however, no one in their right mind would blame you for reneging on your intention to work for A.

So talk to them. Likely scenario is that you make some more industry contacts in a place you'd like to work in the future. Best case scenario, they make you an offer you can't refuse.