# Talking about accepted offer during a job interview

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer

I accepted an offer and after that got an interview opportunity from my dream company. In the interview they had asked me if I have deadlines coming up. I informed them that I had to accept another offer since the deadline was before they invited me to the interview. Will this create a negative opinion with interviewer or HR? Will the decision of considering me for next rounds be affected?

In the offer letter it has been mentioned that the employment is at will and can be terminated any time by both the parties.

Comment: If you accepted an offer, why did you go to the other interview? Of course this will affect, as you taking and accepting another offer completely disqualifies you as a potential candidate (as you already took another).

Comment: I mentioned in the question that it is my dream company and that I have got the interview invitation after the deadline has passed for my offer

Comment: Yes, but even though it where the best company there is, you already took other offer. Going to the interview will only waste your and their time. Does this imply that you are considering in cancelling the offer you already accepted in lie of this new company?

Comment: Yes. I am very much interested in the new company.

Comment: But you accepted another offer, so that door is closed for now. That is why job searching is a delicate process, where one has to take risks. Seems that you played safe (took the other offer) a bit earlier this time, although keep in mind that you only got an *interview opportunity*, when the other company already gave you a *job offer*

Comment: @DarkCygnus WHy would that door be closed?  THey can interview at the new job, if they don't get it, nothing lost but time.  If they do, they quit the job they just accepted (although probably burning a bridge there).  Its a balancing act of if they want the "dream job" enough to burn the one they just took.

Comment: @GabeSechan I said "that door is closed **for now**"... meaning that if you tell them in their face that you "already took another offer" it is almost completely likely that they will lose interest in you, as you are no longer available. Of course, in the future the door can open again...If you want, please include your thought and suggestions in an answer, so we can consider it and so OP can have different POVs

Comment: Yes, probably, but there's nothing you can do about that now. Are you wondering about how to handle this in future or are you simply wondering whether it will affect your chances?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To interview at another company (B) after accepting an offer from company (A)](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/47077/to-interview-at-another-company-b-after-accepting-an-offer-from-company-a)

Comment: @Dukeling I am wondering and tensed about this affecting my chances to proceed for further rounds in the interview.

Comment: I don't understand the logic at all that if they took another job they're somehow no longer available for this job. That logic would preclude anyone who is already in work from interviewing for a new job. If anything, someone who has only just accepted an offer is less of a risk than someone who has been working elsewhere for a while - they're likely on a shorter/zero notice period if there's a probationary period, they have fewer ties to the job etc. The only real issue is that the interviewer may now question whether they might drop _this_ job if another, better offer comes along.

Comment: @Dukeling This is **not a duplicate**, they are related. The linked question asks if it's ethical to go on another interview after accepting an offer, this one wants to know how to break the news gently to the new company. **Very different** questions.

Answer (score 4):

> Will this create a negative opinion with interviewer or HR?

Hard to tell for sure, but I am certain **they won't be too happy to hear you already accepted an offer and still came to the interview**.

If you have already accepted an offer for a job, the correct thing would have been to *decline the invitation to interview*. This would have saved them (and you) the time of interviewing a candidate that already accepted another offer.

> Will the decision of considering me for next rounds be affected?

Surely. Most likely you will no longer be considered for the job, as you explicitly told them you already accepted another offer in another company.

I doubt that any recruiter would want to schedule time with a candidate that is already "taken", as they could focus on others that are available.

Comment: But, I can politely decline the offer I have right? They have not done my background check yet. So, I do not understand the problem in interviewing with other companies.

Comment: You said you already accepted it. That is, you told them "yes, lets do this" and perhaps signed something. Now, the company is starting the on-boarding process. Surely you *could* back up now, but I don't think that would be professional given that you (and no one else) already accepted the offer they gave you... could you please specify exactly what you mean by "I accepted the offer"?

Comment: I signed the offer but the start date is after 7 months and the on boarding process is not going to start any time soon.

Comment: 7 months?! why?... wow, what you are going to do meanwhile? Still, you said you signed something, so that document surely has info specifying what happens if you back up... I think that checking it would also help you. Seems that perhaps you need to rephrase and include these other details in the question

Comment: @nkavuri If your start date is 7 months out, that changes the context of the question significantly.  Are you still in school and scheduling a job for post-graduation, or are you available for work immediately?

Comment: I am a college student and will be graduating in June next year.                 
 This is the phrase in the offer letter. The terms of this letter are not a contract of employment and do not imply employment for any
specific period of time. Rather, employment at *** is at-will, which means that either you or *** may terminate your employment at any time, for any reason and without prior notice

Comment: @nkavuri *please*, update your answer and include those details, as it will surely help. After that I can enhance my answer. Still, regardless of this fact, backing up from an offer you already accepted is not something to be taken lightly (even more if you are backing off on your first offer ever).

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @nkavuri I see them. Will try to enhance when I get time.

Answer (score 3):

How things go is different at every company, in every industry, with every person, so there is no definite answer except from the hiring manager in question.

Part of my job is recruiting software developers. If I would get a candidate that said to me that they had just accepted an offer for Facebook but actually really really wanted to work for me, and I have the feeling from the rest of the interview that that is really true, I don't care the already accepted offer. It would be your own issue to solve that with the other company.

I don't see why some answers mention that recruitment managers would like to select an "available" candidate. If you are willing to let go the other offer and work for them, you are an available candidate.

Answer (score 2):

> Will this create a negative opinion with interviewer or HR?

You basically told them that you are willing to go back on your word with your employer. In many interviewers', HR reps', and potential employers' minds that will certainly create a negative opinion.

> Will the decision of considering me for next rounds be affected?

You will need to wait and see if that is the case. In many cases you'd be dropped from consideration immediately. Maybe you'll be lucky.